# How to determine whether a file has hard links in php

Tags: php

I want to get the number of linked hard-links of a file in PHP (same result as in `ls -l` )

Example :

```
ls -l file1 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 lilo lilo 0 Feb 26 07:08 file1
            ^
```

How can I get this data?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `stat()` function:

```
<?php
$filestat = stat('/path/to/file');
echo 'Number of links to file: '.$filestat['nlink'];
?>
```

A list of all array members `stat()` retrieves can be found in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php).